# Is there a way to see what exactly the "processing triggers" does per-package basis?

Tags: dpkg

As I've understood, the usual "*Processing triggers for < packagename >*" does some package- and system-specific tasks such as add items to a launch menu or update a configuration file. Is there an actual way to see what exactly is being done or altered during this step? Where can one find the exact behaviour of the step?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There is, but it requires digging through some bash scripts for the packages being triggered.

- Suppose the `dpkg` output looks like:

  ```
  Preparing to replace zim 0.52-1 (using .../archives/zim_0.52-1_all.deb) ...
  Unpacking replacement zim ...
  Processing triggers for shared-mime-info ...
  Processing triggers for menu ...
  ```
- Internally, what `dpkg` does is call the `postinst` script for each of these packages with the `triggered` command-line option, and zero or more trigger options.
- So, you simply open `/var/lib/dpkg/info/PACKAGE.postinst` (it's a bash script), and simply look for what happens when `$1` is `triggered`

#### Example: `man-db` triggers

One of the most common "Processing triggers" you'll see is for `man-db`, whenever the package being installed has a *man* page.

If you open `/var/lib/dpkg/info/man-db.postinst`, you'll find this section:

```
if [ "$1" = triggered ]; then
    # We don't print a status message here, as dpkg already said
    # "Processing triggers for man-db ...".
    run_mandb -pq
    exit 0
fi
```

So you can see that `Processing triggers for man-db ...` simply results in the `run_mandb` function (also found in the `postinst` script) being run with the `-pq` option.

> *Helpful Resources:*
>
> 1. [Trying to make dpkg triggers more useful and less painful](http://raphaelhertzog.com/2011/05/30/trying-to-make-dpkg-triggers-more-useful-and-less-painful/)
> 2. [dpkg triggers, the lost how-to document](http://eric.van-der-vlist.com/blog/owark/473/)