# How do I uninstall the Ubuntu Studio desktop package?

Tags: 12.04, uninstall, desktop-environments, ubuntu-studio

I have installed ubuntustudio-desktop for Ubuntu 12.04.1 on my computer.

Then I noticed that there is no practical difference *(with the non studio version)* with the exception of Xfce and new start screen, so I decided to delete it.

Could someone help me to uninstall it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy and paste the complete line below (adapted from Xubuntu instructions [here](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/pureubuntu)):

```
sudo apt-get remove gnome-desktop-data gnome-system-tools gnome-time-admin  gthumb gthumb-data gtk2-engines-pixbuf indicator-application-gtk2 indicator-messages-gtk2 indicator-sound-gtk2 libconfig-inifiles-perl libdigest-crc-perl libencode-locale-perl libept1.4.12 libexo-1-0 libexo-common libexo-helpers libfile-listing-perl libfl-dev libfont-afm-perl libgarcon-1-0 libgarcon-common libgdome2-0 libgdome2-cpp-smart0c2a libgegl-0.0-0 libglade2-0 libgnomevfs2-0 libgnomevfs2-common libgnomevfs2-extra libgoffice-0.8-8 libgoffice-0.8-8-common libgsf-1-114 libgsf-1-common libgstreamer-perl libgtk2-notify-perl libgtk2-trayicon-perl libgtkmathview0c2a libgtkspell0 libhtml-form-perl libhtml-format-perl libhtml-parser-perl libhtml-tagset-perl libhtml-tree-perl libhttp-cookies-perl libhttp-daemon-perl libhttp-date-perl libhttp-message-perl libhttp-negotiate-perl libid3tag0 libido-0.1-0 libilmbase6 libio-socket-inet6-perl libio-socket-ssl-perl libjavascriptcoregtk-1.0-0 libjpeg-progs libjpeg-turbo-progs libkeybinder0 liblaunchpad-integration1 liblink-grammar4 libloudmouth1-0 liblwp-mediatypes-perl liblwp-protocol-https-perl libmailtools-perl libnet-dbus-perl libnet-http-perl libnet-ssleay-perl liboobs-1-5 libopenexr6 libotr2 libots0 librarian0 libsexy2 libsocket6-perl libtagc0 libthunarx-2-0 libtidy-0.99-0 libtie-ixhash-perl libtimedate-perl libunique-1.0-0 liburi-perl libvte-common libvte9 libwebkitgtk-1.0-0 libwebkitgtk-1.0-common libwv-1.2-4 libwww-perl libwww-robotrules-perl libxfce4ui-1-0 libxfce4util-bin libxfce4util-common libxfce4util4 libxfcegui4-4 libxfconf-0-2 libxml-parser-perl libxml-twig-perl libxml-xpath-perl libxss1 lightdm-gtk-greeter lp-solve m4 plymouth-theme-ubuntustudio python-configobj python-glade2 python-gmenu rarian-compat screensaver-default-images sgml-data shimmer-themes thunar thunar-archive-plugin thunar-data thunar-media-tags-plugin thunar-volman ttf-droid xfburn xfce-keyboard-shortcuts xfce4-appfinder xfce4-cpugraph-plugin xfce4-datetime-plugin xfce4-dict xfce4-indicator-plugin xfce4-mailwatch-plugin xfce4-netload-plugin xfce4-notes xfce4-notes-plugin xfce4-notifyd xfce4-panel xfce4-places-plugin xfce4-power-manager xfce4-power-manager-data xfce4-quicklauncher-plugin xfce4-screenshooter xfce4-session xfce4-settings xfce4-systemload-plugin xfce4-taskmanager xfce4-terminal xfce4-utils xfce4-verve-plugin xfce4-volumed xfce4-weather-plugin xfce4-xkb-plugin xfconf xfdesktop4 xfdesktop4-data xfwm4 xscreensaver xscreensaver-data xscreensaver-gl xubuntu-icon-theme ubuntustudio\* && sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop && sudo /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-set-defaults -g unity-greeter
```

Comment: That deletes Audacious and Audacity and other grat programms that I have!

Comment: Sorry, those are also installed by Ubuntu Studio and not part of default Ubuntu - I didn't know you installed them yourself. I've removed them from the list.

Comment: Are on that list other programms?

Comment: The list should now exclude all programs except XFCE built-ins such as Thunar (the file manager). If you have difficulty separating the programs, skip the removal step and just restore the default Unity configuration with `sudo apt-get --reinstall install ubuntu-desktop && sudo /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-set-defaults -g unity-greeter`

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get purge ubuntustudio-desktop
sudo apt-get purge ubuntustudio-default-settings plymouth-theme-ubuntustudio
sudo apt-get --purge autoremove
```

The same instructions can be found on the [Ubuntustudio FAQ](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuStudio/FAQ) page.

Comment: I continue have Ubuntu Studio Session and Xfce Session, I can not uninstall it...

Comment: @legospace9876: try it again with the modified instructions.

Comment: I am doed re-install

Comment: @legospace9876: did it work?

Comment: @January: So very sorry, you're right in that the meta-package does not reinstall all packages (I thought it used to...), but by that same token, the meta-package won't restore the default configuration either, e.g. the greeter which is probably done by `unity-greeter`, etc....

Comment: @izx thanks, you almost managed to shatter my view of the world :-) However, I agree that "reinstall" is not necessary, installing ubuntu-desktop is here to make sure that no packages are missing (and I add --reinstall just by custom). The configurations (lightdm / greeter etc.) should be triggered by autoremove when removing the ubuntustudio decorations / settings / xfce.

Comment: @January: I have personal experience with greeter issue after uninstalling `kubuntu-desktop` a while ago: removing the alternate greeter does not reset to `unity-greeter`, because the [post-removal script](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1198206/) is not set up to do that part, and there appear to be no "default" [triggers](http://askubuntu.com/questions/178773/is-there-a-way-to-see-what-exactly-the-processing-triggers-does-per-package-ba/178800#178800) for `unity-greeter` that would take care of it.

Comment: @January Congrats on 2k...keep it up! ;)

Comment: Hm, but that's a bug, isn't it? I wonder then how it worked for legospace.

Answer (score 0):

I realize that this is a "dead" thread, but, I do have something to add: try 'sudo apt-get remove xfce*, if the big list fails you and you want to get rid of the xfce environment...

Comment: I know regex stuff. But problem is that than xfce* will match some gtk libraries than is needed for Gnome/Unity/etc.