# How to remove the Ubuntu Studio Startup:

Tags: startup, ubuntu-studio

I'm trying to remove the UbuntuStudio startup screen, as I like the vanilla one better and UbuntuStudio's is very slow. I've already followed all the steps in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/186425/how-do-i-uninstall-the-ubuntu-studio-desktop-package)

But I can't seem to get it to work! Anybody have any ideas? I'm pretty stuck.
Running Ubuntu 14.04LTS on a custom built computer with an AMDFX4300 and a Nvidia GeForce8400GS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default/vanilla theme is provided by the `plymouth-theme-ubuntu-logo` package. Install it:

```
sudo apt-get install plymouth-theme-ubuntu-logo
```

Choose it as the preferred theme:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth 
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

The default/vanilla greeter is provided by `unity-greeter`. Install and set it as the default:

```
sudo apt-get install unity-greeter
sudo tee /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/99-unity-greeter.conf <<EOf
[SeatDefaults]
greeter-session=unity-greeter
EOF
```

Comment: Thanks! I just wanted to ask one more thing, it still has a different login screen. Was this an update recently or ubuntu studio, if it was US how do I remove it?

Comment: @waterlubber Updated the answer.