# Remove Ubuntu Studio Desktop Package from Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, unity, gnome, ubuntu-studio

I am completely new to Ubuntu. Just upgraded from 12.04 LTS to 14.04 LTS. And, I installed ubuntustudio desktop package (it looked cool in screenshots). Now I want to uninstall it completely. Could anybody please help?

I checked [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/186425/how-do-i-uninstall-the-ubuntu-studio-desktop-package) but it seems its for 12.04 and not 14.04.

Comment: Can you upload the output of `cat /var/log/apt/history.log` to http://paste.ubuntu.com and link it back here?

Answer (score 0):

Things like `ubuntustudio-desktop` are called *meta packages*, packages without any real content, but that pull in a bunch of other packages as dependencies. This makes them rather tricky to remove without the logs.

I've looked through the stuff `ubuntustudio-desktop` pulls in and figure you should be able to safely remove the following packages:

```
sudo apt-get remove ubuntustudio-desktop xfce4-cpugraph-plugin xfce4-dict xfce4-fsguard-plugin xfce4-indicator-plugin xfce4-mailwatch-plugin xfce4-mixer xfce4-mount-plugin xfce4-netload-plugin xfce4-notes-plugin xfce4-places-plugin xfce4-power-manager xfce4-quicklauncher-plugin xfce4-screenshooter xfce4-smartbookmark-plugin xfce4-systemload-plugin xfce4-taskmanager xfce4-terminal xfce4-verve-plugin xfce4-volumed xfce4-weather-plugin xscreensaver xscreensaver-data xscreensaver-gl xubuntu-icon-theme ubuntustudio-default-settings ubuntustudio-icon-theme ubuntustudio-lightdm-theme ubuntustudio-look ubuntustudio-sounds ubuntustudio-wallpapers xfce4-appfinder xfce4-notifyd xfce4-panel xfce4-session xfce4-settings xfdesktop4 xfwm4 plymouth-theme-ubuntustudio
```

That should clean out almost everything you don't want.

Take a quick look through, just to make sure you don't recognize anything you want to keep. From what you've said in your question I don't think there will be anything.